# How to add point coordinates to a non geo-referenced csv file?

Tags: qgis, csv

I have a csv file with information but not georeferenced. I'd like to load it in QGIS and add points (with coordinates) in the same file and later save as a shapefile. Is there any way to doing that or just creating an independent layer with the points and then joining both layers? If that is the case  should I have a common ID to do that. I do not have one. Does the number ID could work on that?

Comment: Are you going to add coordinates manually or with some automation based on the ID?

Comment: well, I did manually some 600 points already based on township number and range and then converted the points to xy:) I wonder if there is any "automatic" way to do that.

Comment: If you have township number and addresses you may want to use some geocoding service.

Comment: yes I found one. I usually use geocode plugin in qgis and work in the case of names, but in some cases GC doesn't recognize them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably easiest to create IDs using a Spreadsheet software. Then create points with those IDs in QGIS and join the files later.

Another approach would be to add fake coordinates to the csv and then move them to the correct position.

Comment: yep, I did the fake thing for a couple of points that I didn't know exactly where there were located:) Txs!